# Showing variable names for model summary when using a call

Tags: r, naming-conventions, lm

I have a loop for running several models

```
library(MuMIn)
options(na.action = "na.fail")
dat = iris
listX = names(iris[,3:4]
listY = names(iris[,1:2]

for (y in listY){

fm1 <- lm(dat[[y]] ~ dat[[listX[1]]] + dat[[listX[2]]], data=dat)
dd = dredge(fm1)
print(dd)
}
```

When I run this, the output of `print(dd)` shows the variable names as given such as `dat[[listX[2]]]` etc.

How can I change the code so that I can see the actual names of the variables in the model as if I had written the full variables names for each loop e.g.

```
 fm1 <- lm(Sepal.length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, data=dat)
```

Comment: I've amended based on your comments.

Comment: `print(dd, abbrev.names = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

Just compose the formula in the `for` loop using `paste`.

```
for (y in listY){
    fmla <- as.formula(paste(y, paste(listX[1], listX[2], sep = "+"), sep = "~"))
    fm1 <- lm(fmla, data=dat, na.action = na.pass)
    dd = dredge(fm1)
    print(dd)
}
```

**Notes:**

1. You should have started your example with a call to `library`,
   `dredge` is not a `base R` package, it's in package `MuMIn`.
2. The code as you've posted throws an error, I had to use `na.action = na.pass` in the call to `lm` for `dredge` to execute.

**EDIT.**
As lmo noted in the comment, `reformulate` is much simpler and readable than nested `paste` instructions. The loop would then become:

```
for (y in listY){
    fmla <- reformulate(listX, y)
    fm1 <- lm(fmla, data=dat, na.action = na.pass)
    dd = dredge(fm1)
    print(dd)
}
```

Comment: You should explore the use of `reformulate`. It will make formula construction much less awkward. Here `reformulate(listX, "y")` chould replace `as.formula(paste(y, paste(listX[1], listX[2], sep = "+"), sep = "~"))`, though I haven't checked.

Comment: @lmo Thanks, I was unaware of `reformulate`. Edited the code. (Btw, it would be `y` not `"y"`.)